# How to leave/disband my team?

Tags: dota-2

I created a team just to see how it worked. Now I'd like to disband it and join someone else's team, but I can't seem to find any option on the team page (open profile -> click team name at the top).

How can I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: There's apparently an option under some Community section; I don't play DotA 2 though so I can't confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the game, under the Community tab select "My Team". There is a Disband button at the bottom. Note that you need to be the Team Admin to disband the team